# Sorry. No posts in this category yet

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site and there is existing post on the site and every time I check the blog page I get an error "Sorry. No posts in this category yet". can anyone help me with this I have tried to fix the issue but its driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

There are following cases that may cause this issue.

**Case 1 :** If you are upgrade a wp this may happen in this case you have to update paramlinks. (Setting->paramlinks-> select custom->save Changes.)

**Case 2 :** Check your blog page is set.(Go to Administration > Settings > Reading panel.)

**Case 3 :** Add one category and new post add to that category.Check Is it displayed?
There is case where category is broken due some changes in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a post, there is a option to check categories.

So, you should choose a category or categories in which you want to post.

If you didn't chose a category, you can't see it.

And you can edit post and check a category. It will be shown in that category.

Best of Luck........... :)